# Storing parts of string in Array in python

Tags: python

My string contains large paragraph like this:

```
Line= "

      Name       =    AB    | 1-2 |      Name
      ID         =    CD    | 3-4 |      int
      Stu        =    EF    | 5-6 |      Name
      Email      =    GH    | 7-8 |      string
      ID         =    IJ    | 9-10 |     int
      Tea        =    KL    | 1--12 |    Name
      Email      =    MN    | 13-14 |    Name
      ID         =    OP    | 1-2 |      int "
```

I want to store information which come above ID into an array like this:

```
 A[0] = Name       =    AB    | 1-2 |      Name
 A[1] = Stu        =    EF    | 5-6 |      Name
        Email      =    GH    | 7-8 |      string
 A[2] = Tea        =    KL    | 1--12 |    Name
        Email      =    MN    | 13-14 |    Name
```

The array should continue as I have more data in string which is large, the array should be made up automatically, Can someone help?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, you're choice should be a `dict`.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Used your string.

Note: There's probably a cleaner way to do this.

You can use regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> Line = """

  Name       =    AB    | 1-2 |      Name
  ID         =    CD    | 3-4 |      int
  Stu        =    EF    | 5-6 |      Name
  Email      =    GH    | 7-8 |      string
  ID         =    IJ    | 9-10 |     int
  Tea        =    KL    | 1--12 |    Name
  Email      =    MN    | 13-14 |    Name
  ID         =    OP    | 1-2 |      int """
>>> Line = '\n'.join(i.lstrip() for i in Line.strip().splitlines())
>>> newlist = [i.strip('\n') for i in re.split(r'ID.*',Line)]
>>> print newlist[0]
Name       =    AB    | 1-2 |      Name
>>> print newlist[1]
Stu        =    EF    | 5-6 |      Name
Email      =    GH    | 7-8 |      string
>>> print newlist[2]
Tea        =    KL    | 1--12 |    Name
Email      =    MN    | 13-14 |    Name
```

Comment: Error when print newlist[1]: list index out of range

Comment: @hulk007 You must be doing something wrong, as this is also happening to you on jamylak's answer. Did you copy my code exactly?

Comment: print newlist[0] is giving me the whole string without change

Comment: What I don't understand is why you have taken Line = """\, i dont have this, I have line="

Comment: @hulk007 What do you have? The code given in the question is not a valid multiline string

Comment: When I print line variable it has this data, so I think it is string

Comment: Now when I print newlist[0] its removing the field with ID and giving me the whole string