# Storing part of string in array

Tags: python

I modified my previous question, My string contains large paragraph like this:

```
Line= "

      Name       =    AB    | 1-2 |      Name
      ID         =    CD    | 3-4 |      int
      Stu        =    EF    | 5-6 |      Name
      Email      =    GH    | 7-8 |      string
      ID         =    IJ    | 9-10 |     int
      Tea        =    KL    | 1--12 |    Name
      Email      =    MN    | 13-14 |    Name
      ID         =    OP    | 1-2 |      int "
```

I want to store information which come above ID into an array like this:

```
 A[0] =   Name       =    AB    | 1-2 |      Name
 A[1] =   ID         =    CD    | 3-4 |      int
          Stu        =    EF    | 5-6 |      Name
          Email      =    GH    | 7-8 |      string
 A[2] =   ID         =    IJ    | 9-10 |     int
          Tea        =    KL    | 1--12 |    Name
          Email      =    MN    | 13-14 |    Name
```

The array should continue as I have more data in string which is large, the array should be made up automatically, Can someone help?

Comment: exactly the SAME QUESTION as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436036/storing-parts-of-string-in-array-in-python

Comment: I modified some parts, I need field ID too now in my array

Comment: @hulk007 Still the same question, you should have included that in the original to begin with

Comment: @hulk007 but the solution previously given to you is adaptable to add other "fields"

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
A = Line.split("\n")
```

Though I can't tell if you're arbitrarily deciding which lines go into which item...

and then to add to it... do:

```
A.append("Name Wahtever | --55-- | blah Name")
```

Answer (score 0):

take the answer in [Storing parts of string in Array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436036/storing-parts-of-string-in-array-in-python)

modify the regexp split to be `ID` instead of `ID.*`

use a simple series of list manipulations to put the ID back on the front of the newline[1:] elements